# Way to download and install Chrome by script? Python, for Mac

Tags: python, macos

I have a task, and a part of it is to download and install latest Chrome (like step to test something).

And I can't get how I can do it by script (Python). I can download it, but after it I have to execute a lot of actions, like path to install, clicking 'next' in installing window etc.

Maybe, someone knows how can I do it?

Sorry, for stupid question, I am new in programming.

Script for download Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=CHBD&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8ob1rLv26AIVw7LVCh1vgQ5XEAAYASAAEgLHsfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds")
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("js-download-hero")
element.click()
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: do you have the script to download chrome?

Comment: Yes, in pretty primitive way.
Added to description.

Comment: With **homebrew**, use `brew cask install google-chrome`

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: **homebrew** is a brilliant package manager for Macs as Apple don't give you one. It's here https://brew.sh/

Comment: Anyway, thank you! I will try to realise it.